# How to enable ZendX integrated Jquery in Layouts

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am trying to understand why ZendX_JQuery will not work when used directly in a layout. It works perfectly fine when in a view:

- creates the needed code
- puts the JQuery script in the *head* tag

But when used inside the layout

- creates the needed code
- does **not** insert the JQuery script in the *head* tag

Can this be overcome, and how? And, if anyone can answer this, why is it doing this?

To make it perfectly clear, here is what i want to do:

```
    //layout.phtml file
    <head>
    <?php echo $this->jQuery();?>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php echo $this->ajaxLink("Like",

                    "/mod/instr/like/id/".$this->books['id'],

                    array('update' => '#ajaxed',
                    'beforeSend'=>'fadeout'
                    ));
?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    </body
```

It means, that I wish to put a jQuery object inside a layout. I want to put some jQuery related code ***DIRECTLY*** inside my layout file, not just the part that allows jQuery to initialized for the views that require it.

***Edit:***
Ok, so here's the init function in the Bootstrap

```
    protected function _initJqueryLoad()
    {

        $view = new Zend_View();
     // $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->jQuery()->addStylesheet('/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css')
        ->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/jquery.js')
        ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js');
ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);
    }
```

My layout file contains this in the head:

```
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/admin.css'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/form.css'); ?>
<?php 
echo $this->headScript()->prependFile('/js/JP.js','text/javascript','');?>
<?php echo  $this->jQuery(); ?>
</head>
```

So the JQuery should be enabled in every view that uses this layout.
The code that runs in my views, but not in my layouts is:

```
<div id="ajaxed">
<? 
echo $this->ajaxLink("Like",

                    "/mod/instr/like/id/".$this->books['id'],

                    array('update' => '#ajaxed',
                    'beforeSend'=>'fadeout'
                    ));
                     echo $this->ajaxLink("Don't like",

                    "/mod/instr/hate/id/".$this->books['id'],

                    array('update' => '#ajaxed'));?>


</div>
```

Comment: can you post your view, layout and bootstrap code segments?

Comment: Hey check my answer I edited it with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experience the same problem WITH AJAXLINK.

The link is generated using this helper in a LAYOUT, but the JQUERY function which should do the AJAX call in the header NOT.

It works all perfect if I try the same in a VIEW.

Edit: I ended up in copying the ajax-code manually into the layout without using the ajaxlink-helper.

And I opened up a bug report here: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10317

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I add the "echo $this->jQuery()" at the end of my body (i.e. after the ajax link call) it works.  Basically, the problem is that the jquery helper doesn't know about the ajaxlink until it has already echo'ed the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Last edit: I just do not understand the question. I can run jquery code fine in my layout (example I can use a datepicker right there in layout.phtml). Also your ajaxLink showed up just fine. I downloaded the exemple code from zendcast and pasted your code in the layout and it worked. So I do not know what it is that is not working for you sorry for losing your time.

edit: have you tried adding a

```
return $view;
```

At the end of your init. Usually its bette rto return this from a init method in the bootstrap. Maybe this is why nothign seems to load.

What you are doing should work so there must be something wrongin your code. Check this great tutorial about integrating Zendx Jquery he does exaclty what you want. [Zendcast:Working with ZendX_JQuery](http://www.zendcasts.com/working-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/)

Also post some code so we know what might be wrong.

BTW there is an error in your code (not related to the jquery stuff). You echo twice the headlink if you look at the generated code you should see all your stylesheets in double.
the right syntax would be:

```
<?php $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/admin.css'); ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/form.css'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/admin.css')
           ->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/form.css'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help though.

Comment: @Janis have you watched the tutorial? Its like 20 minutes long and everything you want/need to know is there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and yes, I did just look at the cast. I have done everything just like he did in the cast.
The thing is, that he used all of his jQuery inside a view. I for one, want to use it in a layout. That's the thing that isn't working.

Comment: @janis HE DOES. Jump to 6:52 in the video its RIGHT THERE. You just watched 1 minute of it. He migrates from the view to the layout during the video.

Comment: @Iznogood NOPE, HE DOES NOT! He just enables the view (index.phtml) to access jQuery functions, by inserting $this->jQuery(); in the layout. 
And no, I did watch all of it. I am here for help, and if someone offers something to check out, I do.

Comment: Really I dont know what you are looking for then. You asked for a way to enable jquery in your layout. I gave that to you. Things you shoudl consider: the jquery stuff wont show up in your layout if you do not use jquery anywhere. Its put there on a asneeded basis.

Comment: I edited the question. I don't think I can make it more clearer as to what I need.

Comment: You said: does not insert the JQuery script in the head tag. The what does it do instead? Crash? php error? Nohting? puts the jquery inside body instead?

Comment: It inserts nothing in the head. When i use the ajaxLink function directly in my layout, no jQuery include code is inserted in the <head>

Comment: Looking at the code you just posted I notice a double echo. echo echo. If that is in the real code then maybe thatwould throw an error and not include jquery perhaps. I am testing the code now that I am home maybe Ill find something.

Comment: No, it's not a real code,thats just to show what I needed. Something i threw together off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by placing my ZendX Form in the bootstrap.  This will work for any other ZendX element.  The problem with putting anything ZendX related in the layout.phtml file is that by the time you get to your code, the $this->jQuery(); already executed and you're out of luck.

My example has to do with using ZendX in a placeholder that is echoed in the layout.phtml.  I used the exact same code in a Search view and the code worked.  This was driving me crazy!

```
//Bootstrap.php

protected function _initSearchBox(){
     $this->bootstrap('View');
     $view = $this->getResource('view');
     $searchForm = Search_From_Find::tinyFindForm(); //contains autocomplete textbox and submit button
     $view->placeholder('sidebarright')->prepend($searchForm);
     return $view;
}

//layout.phtml
<head>
    //... normal jquery and other head stuff ...
</head>
<body>
     //... normal body stuff like 'echo $this->layout->content();' ...
     echo $this->placeholder('sidebarright');
</body>
```

I hope this helps someone!

Edit:  I also heard, but not personally verified, that echoing using `<?=` instead of `<?php echo` strangely works...